# Angular2 Quckstart npm start not working

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error when I try to run npm start on an Angular2 quickstart app. I've updated node.js and npm to the latest versions, and after updating I deleted the node modules folder and ran npm install and it's still throwing the error.

```
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-website@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
```

My package.json file seems to fine. Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc -p src/",
"build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
"build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
"serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
"serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
"prestart": "npm run build",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:watch\" \"npm run lite-server\"",
"pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
"e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
"preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
"protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
"pretest": "npm run build",
"test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"pretest:once": "npm run build",
"test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
```

},

Comment: So, what's the complete error message? What happens when you just execute npm run build?

Comment: npm run build would still throw the error so I removed this out of my package.json file. Now when I run npm start, it's starting the web server and running like it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run **npm install** in admin mode - that's sudo on unix/linux/mac, and Administrator mode on Windows.

Comment: Why run as admin? I always install node as a regular user app why trust your system to npm?